# How to remove grub2 in favor of another linux installation grub

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot

I'm using Arch Linux Windows 7 And Ubuntu on the same machine, I installed first Windows 7 Then Arch Linux and Then Ubuntu.

The problem is that the grub 2 on Ubuntu is not recognizing my arch Linux installation, and I can't make it look like the arch Linux grub.

My arch Linux installation has a boot partition of about 100mb, it contains the boot stuff of arch, I can make grub 2 on arch Linux recognize the Ubuntu and windows installation so it works better.

So I want to remove the grub on Ubuntu so I can avoid problems with two grub installation on the same machine for example when Ubuntu updates grub I don't have to re-install arch Linux grub.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to uninstall Grub2 in Ubuntu? If not, then what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @mikewhatever That is exactly what the OP said. Unless that he has been expressed wrong..

Comment: I think that you should enter in Ubuntu and uninstall this *software* from there like any package, I hope that someone else confirm this procedure as *safe*. To do so: `sudo apt-get purge grub*`

Comment: @dhampir If some answer have solved your problem, you should upvote it and mark as accepted. If not, you can comment and tell us your results.

Answer (score 0):

The last installed OS, which is Ubuntu, normally takes over the bootloading process.
It's strange that grub in Ubuntu has failed to detect Arch Linux.

***Edit**: The method suggested above by **NikTh** to mount Arch Linux partition before updating grub might probably be the solution to this problem.*

Otherwise, you have 3 options that I can think of:

1. **Manually** entering a grub entry for Arch Linux, which you won't have to enter again if you include it in this file as well: **/etc/grub.d/40_custom**
2. Trying **[Plop Boot Manager](http://www.plop.at/en/home.html)** or **[Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)** (via a live CD/USB) to **boot Arch Linux** and **re-installing grub** there so that it will take over the bootloading process as you wanted.
3. **Reinstalling Arch Linux** so that it takes over the bootloading process as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

Boot into Ubuntu and open a terminal  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Then mount the partition with Arch Linux .. we assume is /dev/sda5 (you can find it with command `sudo fdisk -l`)

mount

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

Then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

I'm almost certain that Arch Linux recognized now.

Above is a workaround , but when the grub be updated again the Arch Linux partition must be mounted otherwise will not recognize it.

If you want to make it permanent , you can add the contents of arch linux from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

If you want to install Arch Linux grub instead of Ubuntu , you can boot in Arch Linux and do

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

above command will install Arch's grub in MBR and do not forget to update it

`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`